# Ubuntu updater offers upgrade to 17.10 on 32-bit machine

Tags: 17.04, 32-bit, do-release-upgrade, 17.10

The Ubuntu updater on a Ubuntu 17.04 32-bit machine offers an upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 with dropped 32-bit support. How could this be?

Comment: There are repositories for 32-bit versions of the software and the community flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu) are still offering 32-bit versions. It is only the **32-bit iso files** that are no longer provided.

Comment: @sudodus I think that's enough for an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are repositories for 32-bit versions of the software** and the community flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu) are still offering 32-bit versions. It is only the 32-bit desktop iso files that are no longer provided.

This means that all the components for upgrading to 17.10 are available.

---

There is also a 32-bit (i386) Ubuntu `mini.iso` file, that you can find via the link

[cdimages.ubuntu.com/netboot/artful/](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/netboot/artful/)

The files is

[archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

The md5sum is found at

[archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/main/installer-i386/current/images/](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/main/installer-i386/current/images/)

In other words, it is possible to get 32-bit versions of Ubuntu 17.10.

---

See also the related link,

[What will happen to i386 software since Ubuntu will drop support to i386 ISOs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962638/what-will-happen-to-i386-software-since-ubuntu-will-drop-support-to-i386-isos/962641#962641)