# Can I upgrade to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS 32-bit?

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, 18.04, 32-bit, unity-greeter

Since 18.04 LTS, Ubuntu has stopped providing installers for the 32-bit variant. Can I install 16.04 LTS, then upgrade it to 18.04 LTS instead?

I assume the correct command would be:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

What will happen if I have `unity-greeter` installed before the upgrade? Supposedly I should end with the 18.04 version of it, but Ubuntu has discontinued Unity in 18.04. (I did actually use Lubuntu with Unity greeter). Or the whole `ubuntu-desktop` for that matter?

Comment: I'm a little confused sorry, but some of the flavors still have 32bit ISO's (eg. Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is available in 32bit, and I'm currently testing the 18.10 Lubuntu 32bit ISO...).  Unity is no longer supported by Canonical for 18.04 LTS (but still is for 14.04 LTS & 16.04 LTS) and has moved to 'universe' or community-supported, so Unity will still work on 18.04 in the same way LXDE, MATE, XFCE does.  `ubuntu-desktop` in 18.04 means GNOME & no longer Unity (Unity is found in `ubuntu-unity-desktop` in 18.04 LTS)

Comment: I don't understand why you have changed your LXDE desktop into a Unity one; that's the main reason of Lubuntu, using the light desktop LXDE -> so if you want Unity, just take the standard Ubuntu and replace Gnome

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu and the other Ubuntu community flavours provide both 64-bit and 32-bit iso files.

You can find the iso files and corresponding checksums via this link

[releases.ubuntu.com/](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

See also the following link,

[Future support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962638/what-will-happen-to-i386-software-since-ubuntu-will-drop-support-to-i386-isos/962641#962641)

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a number of questions ...

Some flavors still have 32-bit ISO's (eg. Lubuntu 18.04 LTS has)

Unity is no longer supported by Canonical for 18.04 LTS (but still is for 14.04 LTS & 16.04 LTS) and has moved to 'universe' or now in the community-supported repository.  Hence Unity will still work on 18.04 in the same way LXDE, MATE, XFCE does.

`ubuntu-desktop` in 18.04 means GNOME & no longer Unity, with the Unity DEsktop found in the `ubuntu-unity-desktop` package in 18.04 LTS